# Rails3 migration, :joins is now ignored but I want to use it for conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, join

I'm in the middle of migrating to Rails 3. I think I finally got everything working in testing and development but now in production (actually in staging, that environment Rails doesn't believe exists) a certain query doesn't work.  It seems like :joins is now ignored.

```
class Organisation
  # Maybe this is relevant, because it has :dongle in it too.
  LICENCE_TABLE_INCLUDES = [:organisation, :user, :owner_organisation, :profile, :dongle,
                            {:nested_licences => [:profile]} ]

  has_many :dongles

  def latest_received_licences_for_each_dongle
    Licence.find(:all,
                 :joins => [:dongle],
                 :include => LICENCE_TABLE_INCLUDES,
                 :conditions => { 'dongles.organisation_id' => id },
                 #  :group => 'dongles.id',       # broken
                 :order => 'dongles.name ASC, licences.created_at DESC').
      group_by {|l| l.dongle.name}.
      sort_by {|d,ls| d}.
      map {|d,ls| ls[0]}

    # Tried to modernise it a little - same results.
    #Licence.
    #  joins(:dongle).
    #  includes(LICENCE_TABLE_INCLUDES).
    #  where(:dongles => { :organisation_id => id }).
    #  order('dongles.name ASC, licences.created_at DESC').
    #  group_by {|l| l.dongle.name}.
    #  sort_by {|d,ls| d}.
    #  map {|d,ls| ls[0]}
  end
end

class Dongle
  has_many :licences
  belongs_to :organisation
end

class Licence
  belongs_to :dongle
end
```

Calling this results in an error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'dongles.organisation_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `licences`.* FROM `licences` WHERE `licences`.`parent_licence_id` IS NULL AND ((`dongles`.organisation_id = 143)) AND (`licences`.parent_licence_id IN (22,23))
mysql2 (0.2.18) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:265:in `query'
```

As you can see, it hasn't added the join into the query. (rails 3.0.17, mysql2 0.2.18 - not updating to Rails 3.2 yet as I'm trying to get 3.0 to work first.)

Comment: Weird code..a lot of questions. For example, why tables(?) in LICENCE_TABLE_INCLUDES are in singular form? And why do you include "organisation" (as a part of LICENCE_TABLE_INCLUDES) to the query for organisations table itself?

Comment: All those relationships are singular just by their nature (a licence has one organisation, one user, etc.) I guess that wasn't obvious because I omitted the other relationships. The organisation is included because we found that if we didn't do it, everything ran quite a bit slower because when we rendered the view, Rails would perform a lookup on the organisation object for every row (10 seconds view render time instead of less than half a second.) It's a query to generate the appropriate licence results for rendering a table of licences so it includes exactly what the table renders.